# Randomly sampling from list values and corresponding names

Tags: r, list, random, sample

What I want to do is randomly sample from the list values (in this case cities) and create a variable from that sample. Also according to the city randomly picked, another variable (country) should contain the country that corresponds to the city of that observation.

```
list <- list(Spain = c("Barcelona", "Madrid"), Austria = c("Vienna", "Salzburg"), 
             France = c("Paris", "Lyon"), Italy = c("Milano", "Roma"))

cbind(Country = c("Italy", "Spain"), City = c("Roma", "Madrid"))
```

Comment: Does each country always have exactly two cities? If not, do you want to randomly sample any city with equal weighting, or any country with equal weighting then the cities within that country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `data.table` below.  The first part makes a data table of names and countries inlcuding the whole dataset, the second samples two rows at random.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- lapply(list, data.frame) |> 
  rbindlist(idcol = "Country") |> 
  setnames(new=c("Country","City"))

dt[sample(.N,2)]

   Country   City
1: Austria Vienna
2:   Italy Milano
```